# sanitizer about one quart of mix with water went into fermentor with wine kit .what should i do if anything

Tags: fermentation

I put a some sanitizer from gallon jug mixed up in the bucket to ferment with wine kit did I destroy it

Comment: It depends on lots of things. What was the sanitizer and the concentration? How big was the batch it got into? How freshly mixed was it? It's hard to venture an answer to the question with the information provided.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **contact vendor** and ask him if consuming it will be dangerous to **consumer's health**. If yes, then throw it away. Period. Don't read any further. If it's not dangerous, proceed.

If you didn't add yeast yet, consider boiling it. Some sanitizers get volatile easily, so that would help. Then try it for taste. If it's acceptable, try fermenting it. Kit yeast tends to be cheap, so why not?

If you already added yeast, wait and see. If you ruined it, you ruined it. No reliable way to get rid of chemicals now, and adding fresh yeast is pretty pointless as they will die, too.

Waiting a week or two costs you nothing, so proceed as normal, and taste before bottling.